# Using "presentViewController" again and again, I will receive memory warning

Tags: ios, swift, memory, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I attempt to load a new UIViewController in this way:

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
let Form:UIViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("form1")
viewName=textField.text!
Form.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
self.presentViewController(Form, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It works successfully, but when I look at the Debug Navigator, I notice that the memory doesn't go lower. So I keep switching the two UIViewControllers using the method above, and the memory increases from 9MB to 30MB. Then I receive memory warning and the App quit.

What should I do...
How can I totally release an UIViewController?

Comment: Don't keep presenting new instances over the top; you should dismiss or unwind back to from the second to the first.  Alternatively maybe your app needs a different style of navigation, such as a tab bar.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it later :D

Comment: You can try to remove/free the unused memory/variables in the viewWillDissapear method. Although ios has auto memory management, sometimes it doesn't clear that immediately especially if you pass the variables between views.

Comment: A modally presented viewcontroller's instance will only go away from the memory if you have called dismissViewController        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) If you haven't done so the memory will be occupied.